# Edit postcode according the country prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, checkout, onepage-checkout

I have to add a simple str_replace() in the postal code at the moment of the checkout.

That's why in some country, there is the use to add a "-" in the postal code that is not recognized by delivery company's . So, i have to edit this at the moment the adress is insert in the check out according the country of the user.

I use the module "onepagecheckoutps" , but i take a look the code of prestashop, and i thought that i have to edit the class "**Address.php**", in the function "**initialize()**", but i'm not sure.

Do you can help me ?

Comment: There are a lot of places where the postcode is read/written from the database, both in the checkout and in the address editing phase.
maybe you'd better intervene in the system that sends it to the carrier and modify it there ?